# Get started link does not work in oracle 11g server

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have started using Oracle database server on Windows 7 64 bit OS and I have encountered the following error.

```
"Error- Windows cannot find 'http://127.0.01:%HTTPPORT%/apex/f?p=4950'. 
 Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again"
```

I tried to change the properties of get_started but it says that the changing cannot be applied on this shortcut.

Comment: Looking through the whole list of answers here, the question is ready to be closed. Multiple ways of achieving the solution.

Answer (score 26):

Simple solution:

You need to directly tell where your http port is. To do so; open up the folder where your Oracle is stored and navigate to server folder( in my case C:\Oracle\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server) in that folder right click to Get_Started file and choose properties. There you can hand type your http port which is usually 8080 in my case: ....127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950

The problem should be solved.

Hope this helps you get through it..

Pinar U.S.

Comment: Thank You; trying to navigate to the uri directly did not work, although changing the **%HTTPPORT%** to **8080** worked like a charm

Comment: This should be selected as answer. Mods, help close this question. The answer is on similar lines like the solution that worked for me: https://community.oracle.com/message/12700773#12700773

Answer (score 13):

You can directly go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950` and you will get Home Page Of your Oracle Database

Or you can make a new shortcut icon and set it's url to the previous link

Answer (score 13):

This is what worked for me on Windows 8.1 with Update 1, 64-bit:

Create a SYSTEM level Environment variable named HTTPPORT with a value of 8080.
Reboot.
Click the Get Started link and this time it will work because it can resolve %HTTPPORT%.

Comment: Although most of the other answers worked, this one solves the underlying problem of the missing system level environment variable.  Worked for me on Win10

Comment: @user3785010 Thank you for providing this solution - it may be a better approach. Worked for me. +1.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution 
Right click on the shortcut > choose properties > go to security tab > Choose Authenticated Users > and give permission to do everything and now try to change the URL you will be able to do it
Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Make sure these services are working:

- OracleJobSchedulerXE
- OracleMTSRecoveryService
- OracleServiceXE
- OracleXEClrAgent
- OracleXETNSListener

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. In my case only `OracleXETNSListener` was running. I started `OracleServiceXE` service. And now the app is working. Both these services are set to start `Automatic` but for some reason `OracleServiceXE` had stopped. In my case only these two services are running, and it's working. I should point out that I also had to setup the `HTTPPORT` environment variable to 8080 long time ago as suggested by user `user3785010`

Answer (score 1):

This article works for me:
 https://orlandoolguin.wordpress.com/2012/06/10/configuracion-de-apex-en-oracle-11g/

Maybe you need unlock the anonymous account to start Apex. Use this code on cmd:

```
C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\db_1>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL> alter user anonymous account unlock; 
User altered.
```

If doesn't work, you can try previous steps defined on the article.

I hope you solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution.
                                                                                               I made Internet explorer my default browser and then add 127.0.0.1 Under 'Add this Web site to the zone'.

Answer (score 0):

Just go where the file (Get_Started) is which is probably ->
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server
And then **RENAME IT** to any other name THAT's IT.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to match the entries in the file:

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\listener.ora

(the entries with the --> mark)

:

```
LISTENER =

(DESCRIPTION_LIST =

(DESCRIPTION =

  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))

--> (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

--> (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myserver.company.com)(PORT = 1521))

)

)

:
```

With the entries in the file:

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

(the entries with the --> mark)

```
:

--> 127.0.0.1 localhost

--> 1.2.3.4 myserver myserver.company.com

:
```

Finally, under Administrator account do:

```
C:> lsnrctl stop

C:> lsnrctl start
```

Solved. No need for changing name, no drag & drop.

Comment: I don't have localhost entry in listener.ora file. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it as administrator or with an admin user. I did it. It works

Answer (score 0):

Check your antivirus program, some of these softwares block the ports, unblock them, there you go it works!

Comment: antivirus on your local host. yes indeed

Comment: it happen to me for more no of times, that i was not able to open up my oracle db servers home page, than i checked into my antivirus program and have unblocked the port of Oracle server which was blocked by antivirus and it worked fine, hope you got it

Comment: right mind's always use the right software, and surprising thing is that one of the best ranking antivirus is doing it for security purposes, and it make's sense.

Answer (score 0):

Surely Oracle will have in some installations an bug that does not add the environment variable %HTTPPORT%

Add new enviroment variable (for user or system) with name HTTPPORT and value 8080  maybe u need restart

Answer (score 0):

To successfully make the Database_Oracle_Application_Express_11gr run do the following :

- do Windows_key + R - it will open Run
- type in services.msc
- select Extended View from down below to see all the services
- hit 'O' key to reach the Services starting alphabetically with 'O'
- find the service named: OracleServiceXE
- go right_click and move to properties
- in properties: set the Startup Type to "Automatic".
  That's it.

try running your Database_Oracle again and successfully gain access.

Comment: I have this problem but the startup type is already automatic.

Comment: Try doing this - Once you open the Service Management Console via services.msc, set the startup type to Automatic(Delayed Start). Do a manual start after applying changes. From the next windows boot, this service will be started automatically without any intervention. I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Type to your browser address bar

http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950

You must change port number 8080, only if you did select different HTTP port during install

Comment: I have no idea how to "change port number 8080" where this link sends me. Also, I didn't change the install defaults, and I'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the oracle server folder like this 
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\Get_Started.url
and open the properties of Get_Started and changed the 
'http://127.0.01:%HTTPPORT%/apex/f?p=4950'
with this
'http://127.0.01:8080/apex/f?p=4950'