# Windows cannot find 'http:/.127.0.0.1:%HTTPPORT%/apex/f?p=4950'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again

Tags: oracle

I am trying to install Oracle Express 11g, after I download the zip file `OracleXE112_Win64` - I unzip it, and open Disk 1 then setup. I go through the entire installation process without any problems. However when I go to open "Get Started" I come across the following error:

```
Windows cannot find 'http:/.127.0.0.1:%HTTPPORT%/apex/f?p=4950'. 
Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.
```

Comment: `%HTTPPORT%` is almost certainly a Windows .bat file variable that doesn't have a value. you'll need either a cfg file change, or a .bat file wrapper to do `set HTTPPORT 4950`. Not sure where you'll need to make that change OR that my syntax for .bat file is correct. Good luck.

Comment: Contact oracle support.

Comment: 'http:/.127.0.0.1:%HTTPPORT%/apex/f?p=4950' path is in correct as no ip starts with '.' .

Answer (score 31):

Try out this url it is work for me

http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950:1:1615033681376854

1. Windows->Services and restarted some of services(OracleJobSchedulerXE,OracleMTSRecoveryService,OracleServiceXE,OracleXEClrAgent,OracleXETNSListener) and it works for me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQevo.png)

Comment: you only need to use the first part (i.e. [http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950](http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950) I found the answer of how to fix the issue using advice from a duplicated [StackOverFlow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892261/get-started-link-does-not-work-in-oracle-11g-server)

Comment: Work Fine for me... Thanks Very Much

Answer (score 8):

Open your browser and type instead of "http:/.127.0.0.1:%HTTPPORT%/apex/f?p=4950"

type "http:/.127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950"   you can reach home page.

you can set the HTTPPORT as 8080 in environment variables, the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 5):

TLDR; Uninstall and re-install using admin account.

I encountered this error after installing Oracle Express 11g 64 bit using a standard account. After looking for a fix on various sites I realized that the issue was most likely caused by an incorrect setting. Different people suggested editing various files which I was not interested in doing. I found one person who claimed that the issue was a registry setting. Since I used a standard account to install I thought that maybe the registry setting could not be altered using a standard account. So I uninstalled and re-installed using an admin account and it just worked.

Answer (score 5):

You can directly go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950` and you will get Home Page Of your Oracle Database.

> Right click on the shortcut > choose properties > go to security tab >
>   Choose Authenticated Users > and give permission to do everything

and now try to change the URL you will be able to do it.

Hope this help

Answer (score 3):

Change `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`

For example,

Change

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4500:1003:437338575006149::NO:::
```

to

```
http://localhost:8080/apex/f?p=4500:1003:437338575006149::NO:::
```

Answer (score 3):

Reading through all these answers, they failed to show the "correct" way of doing it according to Oracle.

Oracle is the only software company I know that heavily relies on custom environment variables. To add %HTTPPORT% to your environment variables, you first need to search for "System Environment Variables" in Windows. There, you should find a button "Change Environment Variables". In the new window, select "New" and type in HTTPPORT as name and 8080 as value.
Now, log off and on again, and it magically works!

Comment: in `Environment Variables` window, "New" under `User variables` or `System variables`?

Comment: @i.n.n.m: That is a good question. It should work in both, and using it in User Variables makes it local to your current user. So if Oracle is installed for all users, use System Variables, else user User Variables.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed Oracle 11g XE on Windows 10 OS. It's installed successfully on my PC but it's showing error which is :
**Error:**
"windows cannot find 'http //127.0.0.1:%httpport%/apex/f?p4950"

**Just follow some steps**

In SQL command prompt just type

sql> net start OracleServiceXe 
after start the Oracle server.

Type 
SQL> Connect SYS / System as SYSDBA / SYSOPERA

Then type your password which is given by you at the time of installation of Oracle 11g XE. (Press enter).

but You can get login on oracle through this

Note:
( My suggestion to you just type port after http://127.0.0.1:[PortNumber]/apex/f?p=4950 )

http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950

I got loged in successfully.

Answer (score 2):

In my case port 8080 are already use by my local xampp server during oracle  installation software check un used port like pop window appear for me
[image]

so for me url is http://127.0.0.1:8081/apex/f?p=4950:1:4076881202565564

Answer (score 2):

I think it occurs due to the missing of environment variable named HTTPPORT. Just create that environment variable as 8080 will resolve the issue. or replace HTTPPORT as 8080 in the URL.

try this, **http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950**

Answer (score 1):

plz change %HTTPPORT% as 8080 its working for me

Comment: please improve upon answers already given especially for 5 word answers

Comment: Isn't this basically what all the other answers have said?

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this issue

> Error- Windows cannot find 'http://127.0.01:%HTTPPORT%/apex/f?p=4950'. 
>    Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again

After some research work, I found out that my `HTTPPORT` ie. `8080` was occupied by `Apace HTTP Server` and hence connection by `OracleServiceXE` could not be established.

What I did to solve this issue was :

1. Go to Windows -> Services, found out `Apache2.4` and manually stopped it to free my `8080` port.
2. Clicked on  `Start Database`, and I received message :

> The OracleServiceXE service is starting.............. The
>   OracleServiceXE service was started successfully.

3. Manually entered `http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950` url to my browser which auto redirected me to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950:1:3763261197573303`

That's it my issue got resolved.

In order to remember this new url and make sure that next time whenever I hit `Get Started` I should be redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950:1:3763261197573303` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950`, what I did was :

1. Browse to `Directory:\OracleDatabase\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server` and search for `Get_Started.html`.
2. Right Click on `Get_Started.html` and select `Properties`
3. Modify your url and click `Apply`

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error too, it occurs because %HTTPPORT% isn’t part of the system variables yet.

The solution to this is NOT by manually typing in the url to your browser, which works but you have to keep doing it every single time.

Simply goto “this pc” or “my computer” right click on it and select properties, then select “advanced system settings” 
When the new window comes up select “Environment Variables...”

Now under system variables click new to create a new system variable.
Type HTTPPORT into the variable name text box,
Then type 8080 into the variable value text box.
Click OK, close the windows and logout!

Thats an important step, make sure you log out. When you log back in, click the get started icon again and it will open without errors.

✌️

Answer (score 0):

If any other application is installed on your system which is using port:8080, then try other port like 8081 or uninstall and during installation it will prompt on which port it will run the Oracle DBA server.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Oracle Express Edition and I have the same error. One of the possible reason that is maybe your user does not have permission to open this shortcut. Here is how I solved the problem.

**1. Right-click the shortcut and select the `properties`.**
[image]

**2. Now click the `Open File Location`.**
    Now you will see there is a `Get_Started` shortcut. 
[image]

**3. Now right-click the `Get_Started` and select the `properties`. Then select your user and give permission to your user in the `security` tab.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just check that Oracle services  enabled

in windows

CTRL + ALT + DEL

see picutre

[image: windows services for oracle]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and when I search here on Stack Overflow and out I've combined what I found and it works for me. Just follow this:

1. Go to the icon of oracle right click on it choose : open file location.
2. Choose the get started right click on it choose properties on the URL add what is between brackets to the end of the URL (:1:405838811476023). Or just copy this URL:
   http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950:1:1486912860795003
   and put it there instead of the old one
3. Click on apply.
4. Go back to the first step double clicks and it will work.